# Why is my form blinking

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, drawing

I've implemented a simple multithreaded Server\Client game as an assignment for my college.

on the client side in addition to the main thread there are:

1-thread which is responsible of drawing the play ground and the players on the form.

2-thread to communicate with the server to send the directions and receive the location and other information.

first I used the invoke technique but it didn't work because I was using the Graphics after it disposed. see [Draw on a form by a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714358/draw-on-a-form-by-a-separate-thread#comment13919956_10714358)

so In order to avoid that and regularize the drawing thread, I just raising the flag 'Invalidate' every specific time on the drawing thread and leave the actual handling of it to the main thread:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Draw()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (map.hasGraph)
        {
            map.Draw(e.Graphics);
            if (this.Index != null)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, Rectangle);
            if (OpponentIndex != null)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(OpponentBrush, OpponentRectangle);
        }
    }
```

the problem here that the form is blinking in arbitrary fashion even though I'm using double buffering, and the blinking is reduced when I increase the sleeping time for the drawing thread, but I think 200ms is already too much.
any advice?

[Edit]

I realized that I'm setting the double buffering flag from the code and from the property editor which made the problem (this may be a fool idea) but I spent half an hour testing my code with one of the flags and with both of them, the problem raised when I set the double buffering flag from two places, my problem is solved but please now I need to know if this could be what solved it.

Comment: Show how you are using double-buffering, there's no evidence for it in the snippet.

Comment: This might happen if you blank it out and then draw your buffered image onto it. Rather than your buffered image over the last one.

Comment: Can we assume this is winforms?  what is the control that is painting, picturebox, panel....?

Comment: @HansPassant: I added the double buffering setting code

Comment: Set the DoubleBuffered property to true instead.

Comment: @K'Leg: yes it's winforms and the panel is painting.

Comment: There is also no evidence that you are drawing from a seperate thread.

Answer (score 2):

It must get worse and worse the longer it runs right?

Everytime your program paints it launches draw, which has an infinite loop, which calls paint, which calls draw in another infinite loop.  IT seems you have a circular reference here.  If I can assume Map.Draw is private void Draw()

There is a far easier solution to this, draw everything to a bitmap then draw the bitpmap in the onPaint event.

```
Bitmap buffer=new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height); //make sure to resize the bitmap during the Form.Onresize event
Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.Interval= 100;
    timer.Tick+=......
    timer.Start()
}

//the Timer tick event
private void timer_tick(....
{
    if (map.hasGraph)
    {
         using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
        {
            //You might need to clear the Bitmap first, and apply a backfround color or image
            //change color to whatever you want, or don't use this line at all, I don't know
            g.Clear(Color.AliceBlue);

            if (this.Index != null)
                g.FillRectangle(Brush, Rectangle);
            if (OpponentIndex != null)
                g.FillRectangle(OpponentBrush, OpponentRectangle);
        }
     panel1.BackgroundImage=buffer;
     }
}
```

**Note** I did not test this for syntax accuracy.

Comment: I can explain this better if you wish.  But it should remove alot of your flickering issues, I set the frequency at 10 frames per second, change the tick value to whatever you want, you had it at 5 frames per second, change the timer.Interval= (in ms)

Comment: I may not described the idea very clear, I'm sure I don't have circular reference because the draw method is the starting method of a separate thread so no one is calling it but the responsible thread.anyway see the edition.

Answer (score 0):

The memory of the system might be quite low for the operation executed.
read more about it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an image which will be used to store last rendered scene.
2. Create new thread whith will draw to the image
3. Create a timer whitch will refresh image
4. Copy image to form on timer tick