# Is it possible to pass parameters in a Thread?

Tags: c#

Hey all coders i am trying to pass a graphics parameter through a thread but each time i do i get a expectation error can someone please help.

My Code:

```
private Thread GraphicThread;

public void GraphicThreading(Graphics g)
{
    GraphicThread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        Render(g);
    });
    GraphicThread.Start();
}
public void Render(Graphics g)
{
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 0, 0, 100, 100); 
}
```

My Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

See the problem is that because i have a panel that is double buffered i need to draw directly into it i tryed that method you just linked Arkady before and it does not give me any errors but it does not display anything because it needs to be drawn directly into the panel so it can be buffered.

So this is my main class:

public partial class Engine : Form
    {
        //Command line will be seen
        public const int ENGINE_DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1041;
        public const int ENGINE_DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 539;

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    public Engine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private GraphicEngine GraphicalEngine;
    private void display_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*-SimpleEngine: DoubleBuffering And GraphicsEngine Has Started-*");
        display = new DoubleBuffering();


        GraphicalEngine = new GraphicEngine();

        GraphicalEngine.GraphicThreading(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void Engine_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
    }
}
```

And this is the class that the display_paint function is sending data to:

```
 class GraphicEngine
{
    //Graphic Objects
    private Thread GraphicThread;
    //Rate
    //Functions
    public void GraphicThreading(Graphics g)
    {
        GraphicThread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            GraphicalDisplay(g);
        });
        GraphicThread.Start();
    }


    float Pos = 0;
    public void GraphicalDisplay(Graphics g)
    {
        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), 0, 0, Engine.ENGINE_DISPLAY_WIDTH, Engine.ENGINE_DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        while (true)
        {

            g.DrawImage(SimpleEngine_Improved.Properties.Resources.player, (int)Pos, (int)Pos);

            Pos+= 0.1f;
            Thread.Sleep(2);
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Are you using GDI (a `Graphics` object) from `OnPaint` in a background thread? Or is this a `Graphics` instance you created yourself?

Comment: OnPaint with the panel and then from there i send it down into the GraphicThreading function

Comment: You can't thread that function, the `grapics` object that is passed in to that function may be disposed before you paint on it.

Comment: Is there another way that i can display graphics in a panel, which btw i am using a double buffered panel as well?

Comment: Sure, do your own manual double buffering, draw to a thread local `Bitmap` then when yoyu finish draw the bitmap on the UI on the UI thread. However if you are doing so much with the UI you need to thread the drawing you might be better off ditching winforms and going with a library that is designed to have rapid updating done, like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) or XNA

Comment: Is this how i could do it to implement it with my thread? ` Bitmap display = new Bitmap(100, 100);
  Graphics displayGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(display);` and yeah i know XNA and Unity but i want to try making something without any extra libs besides the default ones.

Comment: I think a solution for your problem has been described already on stackoverflow here: [Draw on a form by a separate thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714358/draw-on-a-form-by-a-separate-thread)

Comment: See the problem is that because i have a panel that is double buffered i need to draw directly into it i tryed that method you just linked Arkady before and it does not give me any errors but it does not display anything because it needs to be drawn directly into the panel so it can be buffered.

Comment: If you did the code from the other question and it still is not working please show a complete, recreatable example of it not working as a edit to your question showing your implmentation and I will gladly vote to reopen it question. (Or you may be better off asking a new question showing what you implmented and explaining the results you are getting)