# Print with Task

Tags: c#, printing, task-parallel-library

I'm creating a label with Graphics and printing it with PrintDocument, before i didn't had any problems because the information on the label was repeated multiple times so i would just set copies and everything would work fine.

But now each label has a different information so it freezes the ui because i have to loop PrintDocument.Print() multiple times instead of setting copies.

i tried:

```
 Task t = new Task(() =>
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < Copies; i++)
                        {
                            printDocument1.Print();                                
                            Label_Copies++;
                        }
                    });
 t.Start();
```

I'm drawing the label on printDocument1_PrintPage with this code:

```
int base_y = 5;
int base_x = 7;
int fontsize_bold = 8;
int fontsize_regular = 7;

RectangleF baserect = new RectangleF(base_x, base_y + 20, 0, 0);
SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White);
SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
string font = "Cabriolli";
Pen mypen = new Pen(blackBrush);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 320, 130));
//e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen, 1, 1, 225, 140);
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.DrawString("REMETENTE:",
     new Font(font, fontsize_regular, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
     Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 10;
e.Graphics.DrawString("BETA COMERCIAL IMPORTADORA LTDA",
    new Font(font, fontsize_bold, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 15;
e.Graphics.DrawString("DESTINATARIO:",
   new Font(font, fontsize_regular, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
   Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 10;
e.Graphics.DrawString(Etiqueta_Destinatario, // *cliente
    new Font(font, fontsize_bold, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 15;
e.Graphics.DrawString("NOTA FISCAL:",
  new Font(font, fontsize_regular, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
  Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y + 3, 0, 0));
e.Graphics.DrawString(Etiqueta_Nota, // *nota
    new Font(font, 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 68, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 15;
e.Graphics.DrawString("PEDIDO:",
   new Font(font, fontsize_regular, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
   Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y + 3, 0, 0));
e.Graphics.DrawString(Etiqueta_Pedido, // *pedido
    new Font(font, 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 43, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 15;
e.Graphics.DrawString("Etiqueta numero:",
new Font(font, fontsize_regular, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 140, base_y - 20, 0, 0));
if (Copias.Checked)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Etiqueta_Copias.ToString(),
    new Font(font, 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
   Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 140, base_y, 0, 0));
}
else
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Etiqueta_Copia.ToString(),
     new Font(font, 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 140, base_y, 0, 0));
}
e.Graphics.DrawString("VOLUMES:",
   new Font(font, fontsize_regular, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
   Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y + 3, 0, 0));
e.Graphics.DrawString(peças_textbox.Text, // *quantidade
    new Font(font, 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 53, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 25;
e.Graphics.DrawString("TRANSPORTADORA:",
   new Font(font, fontsize_regular, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
   Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y, 0, 0));
base_y += 14;
e.Graphics.DrawString(nota_transportadora_combobox.Text, // *transportadora
    new Font(font, 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x, base_y, 0, 0));
whiteBrush.Dispose();
blackBrush.Dispose();
mypen.Dispose();
```

but it doesn't work is there a way to fix it?

-the information comes from the ui
-500~ labels
-the only information that changes from label to label in those copies is

```
    if (Copias.Checked)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Etiqueta_Copias.ToString(),
    new Font(font, 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
   Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 140, base_y, 0, 0));
}
else
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(Etiqueta_Copia.ToString(),
     new Font(font, 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular),
    Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(base_x + 140, base_y, 0, 0));
}
```

its basically a counter for the label number...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `it doesn't work`.  What doesn't work?  Nothing prints?  An exception is thrown?

Comment: @LarsTech yes nothing prints

Comment: This code works when called without a task? If so, my guess is that drawing graphics requires calls to happen on the dispatcher, and your task is executed on a taskpool thread.

Comment: @Chris yes the code works without task but the ui freezes, thats my problem ;/

Comment: You can try splitting the work into independent pieces and scheduling it on the Dispatcher. That way, the UI will respond inbetween tasks (but still freeze for the duration of each task).

Comment: @Chris problem is you cant PrintDocument.Invoke so it wouldnt even work i tried yesterday... and even if it did it wouldnt be a solution becouse as i said it takes only 1 second to print one label.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, your code, if we ignore the printer's spooling side, is pure WinForms UI.
Since that the work is multiplied, let's say by a 100 copies, it becomes too much Continous UI.

Tasking isn't helping you because I think the printing side is "fire and forget", so even if the printing took 30 seconds per sticker, the printing side would return immediately, and let the UI start it's heavy work on the next sticker, almost immediately after it finishes the last one.

let's say the UI has to work 1 second per sticker, you are looking at a 100 seconds UI blocking...
My suggestion:

Rely on the fact that the printing behind takes 20 seconds: Launch the printing using a timer instead of a loop. Set it to 5, 10 or 20 seconds (match with your printer's speed). Each time you will fire the timer, it will UI process 1 sticker only, and then rest in peace for 5, 10, or 20 seconds...

Comment: i dont think this would help firstly becouse what makes the ui freeze is       printDocument1.Print(); , and i print 500~ labels of each type and the printer takes less than one second to print one label, the problem here is that only 1 information that doesnt come from the ui changes so i cant make copies i would have to be pages or a loop like that, timer doesnt work becouse it would take too long to print everything and it would still freeze the ui.

Comment: Maybe you can try this [Draw on a form by a separate thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718805/2381899). Maybe it will allow you to print without actually drawing the bitmap to the form.
Regardless, timer is easy to try, and while some improvement is not a solution, it's still an improvement...