# Form freezes when holding mouse left down on the title bar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On Windows Forms app, when I place mouse pointer to title bar of form, left button down and hold it (but don't move the pointer), the event loop freezes for some short period of time.

Also, holding left button down on the close button on the title bar freezes the form indefinitely.

I want to avoid this freeze because my app is doing some real-time update of drawing triggered by System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

This is sample application. This application just shows a form, and blinks its color so rapidly:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var form = new Form();
            var flag = false;
            var timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100;
            timer.Tick += (o, e) =>
            {
                var brush = flag ? Brushes.LightGray : Brushes.DarkGray;
                using (var g = form.CreateGraphics())
                    g.FillRectangle(brush, form.ClientRectangle);
                flag = !flag;
            };
            timer.Start();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

This sample app keeps blinking all the time. But when holding mouse left down on the title bar (or close button on title bar), it stops blinking.

I guess this issue is related to [DragDetect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms646256(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but have no idea about how to avoid it.

Comment: I think this is something by design, check if your event is triggering, if it is triggering and but still not drawing. You can test this behavior in any other animated window e.g. Windows Task Manager's Performance Tab.

Comment: I did printf debug and event was not triggered. Windows Task Manager freezes similarly. But Media Player doesn't freeze.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the blinking part of the code to a separate thread, the blinking should become independent by any other event, and the application will keep blinking even thogh you keep the mouse down on close button.

Comment: I checked this but unfortunately it didn't work. Separated worker thread can run in parallel with freezing UI thread (massage pump), but to update drawing I have to use Control.Invoke and it needs UI thread running to process request from worker thread.

Comment: Drawing on a container from separate thread then showing it on paint event should work. You can try the sample of code from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714358/draw-on-a-form-by-a-separate-thread