# Drawing in a Task / Thread

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Im facing some issues to draw a rectangle  `(System.Drawing)` in a Panel. The thing is that I have to do this using a Task in order to keep the UI responsive.
I suspect that this is a `thread-safety` issue, but Im not sure. When I was having thread-safety issues I was troubleshooting it using *`Invoke`*. But it doesnt seems to work with *`System.Drawing`* methods.

**This is my code (triggered in the Panel Paint event):**

```
    private void setup(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        int x = 50;
        int y = 50;
        int w = 15;
        int h = w;
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);

        Point location = new Point(x, y);
        Size size = new Size(w, h);

        Task t = Task.Run(()=> {

            Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(location, size);

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color), Rect);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), Rect);

        });
    }
```

P.S: I have intention to make a Class to do all the drawing stuff, I don't know if it can change things later.

**Error**:

> The e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color), Rect); line is returning
>   an *OutOfMemory* excpetion.

**EDIT**:

Regarding the topic [Draw on a form by a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714358/draw-on-a-form-by-a-separate-thread), when I use this buffer I stop having the error, but it doesn't draw my rectangle at the Panel. Code below:

```
        Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);

        Task t = Task.Run(()=> {
            Rectangle Rect = new Rectangle(location, size);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer)) {
                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color), Rect);
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), Rect);
            }
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                BackgroundImage = buffer;
            }));
        });
```

**EDIT 2:**

About this code above, it doesn't seems right because it's not using the `PaintEventArgs` of the Panel. That's probably the reason that I don't see the rectangle at the Panel.

**EDIT 3:**

This code above works fine if I don't use a Panel. It can draw directly in the Form (when I use the FormLoad event). I just have to know how to do it inside the Panel.

Comment: If your current drawing code (without the task) not responsive?

Comment: you will be drawing to a disposed graphics object... Computer says no

Comment: I would reccomend using a buffer to draw on in your task. Something like: `Bitmap buffer = new Bitmap(width,height);Graphics g=Graphics.FromBitmap(buffer);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw on a form by a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714358/draw-on-a-form-by-a-separate-thread)

Comment: @TheGeneral  I just edited my topic. I still have a problem even using the buffer

Comment: @john Works perfectly without the Task

Comment: Is there a specific reason why wou would wait 5 seconds after drawing the rectangle and then do nothing? Otherwise I'd see no reason why the handler can't run synchronosly. It doesn't do anything really time consuming.

Comment: @Adwaenyth Only for debugging purposes, but it doesn't affect the error in any way

Comment: I mean do you plan to add some time consuming stuff in there so that running on a different task would even be a benefit for your code? Otherwise, if it is just and event handler, you could try using and `async/await` method as EventHandlers may have void as return type. It should also not block the UI thread unnecessarily.

Comment: @Adwaenyth Yes, Im planning to draw more objects in the Panel and even simulate movement of those. I believe that async/await won't help me with that.

Comment: If you're wanting to interact with UI objects (and `PaintEventArgs` and anything you access through it are definitely in this class), you need to be on the UI thread. I think the whole plan here is on a hiding to nothing. Yes, you can construct some *images* in other tasks or threads, but you're not going to be able to do that *whilst* you're processing a `Paint` event. Look to other avenues such as splitting up your work (if it's taking too long) into work that can be done in a callback from the `Timer` component.